# AWS Cognito PHP SDK - Unable to verify secret hash for client

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-cognito, refresh-token, aws-php-sdk

So far I created user pool, app client and marked Generate client secret box.
I am able to register, login, logout.
But I'm unable to refresh token using REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH flow.

```
private function refreshConf($refreshToken, $hash)
{
    return [
        'AuthFlow' => 'REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH',
        'ClientId' => $this->client_id,
        'UserPoolId' => $this->userpool_id,
        'AuthParameters' => [
            'REFRESH_TOKEN' => $refreshToken,
            'SECRET_HASH' => $hash
        ]
    ];
}

public function refreshToken(string $refreshToken, string $hash)
{
    try {
        $conf = $this->refreshConf($refreshToken, $hash);
        $result = $this->client->InitiateAuth($conf);
        $result = $result->toArray();
        logger($result);
        if (isset($result['AuthenticationResult'])) {
            return [
                'error' => false,
                'message' => 'SUCCESS',
                'data' => $result
            ];
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        logger(get_class($e));
        return [
            'error' => true,
            'message' => $e->getAwsErrorMessage()
        ];
    }
}
```

And my function to generate secret hash:

```
public function cognitoSecretHash($username)
{
    $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $username . $this->client_id, $this->client_secret, true);
    return base64_encode($hash);
}
```

Secret hash is stored in User model during registration so I can send it when I want to refresh the token. But every time `Aws\CognitoIdentityProvider\Exception\CognitoIdentityProviderException`
is thrown. And I get the response `Unable to verify secret hash for client d***************9`.
So far I've spent hours trying too google the solution. There seems to be a problem with javascript SDK, but no mentions of PHP. I've gone through AWS documentation and can't find what am I doing wrong. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: AWS SDK for PHP 3.x documentation about InitiateAuth https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-idp-2016-04-18.html#initiateauth

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same issue and can´t seem to find much info

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried just sending the client secret specifically (without hashing) for the refresh token call? That works in my current project.

Answer (score -1):

if the client has `client_secret` generated, then you have to replace:

```
'SECRET_HASH' => $hash
```

with

```
'SECRET_HASH' => $this->client_secret
```